# Spinner alert Ionic

Tags: user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic2, alert, uialertcontroller

I want show an alert with a spinner in subTitle like:

[image]

I tryed, without success:

```
this.alertCtrl.create({
   title: 'Verificando',
   subTitle: '<ion-spinner name="dots"></ion-spinner> foo bar'
});
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: can you show your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately AlertController from Ionic 2 doesn't offer a way by default to embed HTML code inside the title/subtitle attribute. Will this alert be used only when you are loading something?
On that case I suggest that you use the LoadingController component, with LoadingController it's possible to insert html embedded code as the content attribute.

For instance, on this case I have created a custom CSS animation on class `.sp .sp-slices` that I'm inserting on the LoadingController variable named loadingCtrl:

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            spinner: 'hide',
            content: '<div class="sp sp-slices"></div>'
          });
this.loading.present();
```

Using this should give you flexibility enough to adjust the LoadingController component to look exactly like what you need.

Ionic 2 also offers other LoadingController designs that are much closer to the native default look for Android iOS and Windows Phone. It's worthy taking a look at their API documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/

Comment: I used `loadingCtrl` with `alertCtrl`, to show a prompt alert when backdrop's clicked. If the user clicks yes, my subscription is cancelled, if users clicks no, my subscription re-runs.